# Do Predators take the skulls of other predators as trophies?

Tags: predator, predator-series, the-predator

I recently saw a poster for the upcoming movie *The Predator*, showing a predator's hand holding a predator's skull as a trophy. At first I thought it didn't make sense and should be a human skull, but now I'm wondering if there has ever been any case of a predator taking another predator's head as a trophy?

[image: The Predator poster]

Comment: Well, the poster says "the hunt has evolved" so I suppose on Sept 14 we will see if the case occurs for the first time...

Answer (score 7):

In *Predators* (2010) we see two different tribes of predators, the Jungle Hunter Clan and the Super Predator Clan. In the film we see the [Crucified Predator](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Crucified_Predator) of the Jungle Hunter Clan is tied up in the camp area.

[image: Crucified Predator tied up]

From this we can infer that the species does hunt its own in some circumstances. Since it has been shown that they take trophies from worthy prey we can assume that at least some predators have trophy skulls of other predators in their trophy room.

The [Berserker](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Berserker_(Game_Preserve_Planet)) in the same film decapitates the Crucified Predator and if it had survived the film we can assume it would have used it as a trophy.

[image: The Berserker about to decapitate the Crucified Predator]

Comment: Nice answer, I've expanded it to add in some sources and also some images with extra reasoning for your case.

Comment: You also may want to [register your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161),

Comment: You may also consider [merging your accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).